# Appium - Android refetching and refreshing network status

Tags: java, android, automation, appium, mobile-application

I am testing my app's ability to switch between online and offline mode but every time I go offline and come back online Appium is not able to find any of the elements. I am assuming that there is a loss of network here.

I have tried using these commands :

```
wd.getPageSource();
wd.navigate().refresh();
Thread.sleep();
new WebDriverWait(wd,10);
```

but none of them seem to work.

Is there any way I can refresh the network, make a network call or refresh the app itself.

Thanks in advance,
Shyam.

Comment: Could you please try 'adb connect <your phones ip address>' to reconnect your device?

Answer (score 1):

You can use NetworkConnectionSetting class to refresh(turn On/Off) the network. Look [here](http://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/NetworkConnectionSetting.html)

Answer (score 0):

It also happened with me but only with emulator, it worked fine in real device.
As when we use emulator and and switch the from any application, it stops adb itself in case of emulator.

Please try with real device it will work fine.

Comment: Its not working for me in the real device.  will try the above methods

Comment: yes above will surely work here is the sample code :
AndroidDriver driver;
NetworkConnectionSetting ncs = new NetworkConnectionSetting(airplane, Wifi, data);
driver.setNetworkConnection(ncs);